# Changing single digit number to double digit in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I add a zero to a to the output for a percentage?
Here is the code:

```
    var margin = 0;             
    if(total_quantity>1000){margin = .32;}
    else if(total_quantity>575){margin = .35;}
    else if(total_quantity>143){margin = .36;}
    else if(total_quantity>71){margin = .38;}
    else if(total_quantity>36){margin = .40;}
    else{margin = .55;} 
    document.getElementById('margin').value=margin;
```

The output of the .40 margin is always 4%. I need it to be 40%

Comment: why it's `4%` and not `.4`? where is the conversion code?

Comment: I don't see how `0.40 ` is `4%` ? If you are multiplying every `margin `by `100`, you'd get `40%` for `0.4` and `35%` for `0.35`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var margin = 0;
if (total_quantity > 1000) {
    margin = .32;
} else if (total_quantity > 575) {
    margin = .35;
} else if (total_quantity > 143) {
    margin = .36;
} else if (total_quantity > 71) {
    margin = .38;
} else if (total_quantity > 36) {
    margin = .40;
} else {
    margin = .55;
}
function formatPercentage (decimalNumber) {
    return parseInt(decimalNumber * 100, 10); + "%";
}

document.getElementById('margin').value = formatPercentage(margin);
```

---

**EDIT**

You said **"but I'm getting two percent signs"**... then this should be your `formatPercentage` function:

```
function formatPercentage (decimalNumber) {
    return parseInt(decimalNumber * 100, 10);
}
```

Comment: [Solved]That fixed it, but I'm getting two percent signs.

Comment: Removing "%" will do. By why the heck margin = .40 does not work while margin = .38 does?!

Answer (score 0):

In your post you probably wanted to say "The output of the .40 margin is always .4%. I need it to be 40%", right?
Multiply your margin by 100 and you will get 40% instead of .4%

Comment: In the output, I'm getting 32%, 35%, 36%, 38%, 55%, and 4%. I didn't write the code, I'm just trying to correct it.

Comment: Wow. Okay, now I am puzzled myself!